# JTextArea and JButton will not add to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My text area and buttons will not add to the panel to be displayed when I run the Java program. All I see when I run the program is the panel without any of the text areas and buttons. How do I get the text areas and buttons to show up?

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bookstore");
    frame.setSize(500, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.append("\n" + bk[0]);
    panel.add(textArea);

    JButton btnFirst = new JButton("First");
    GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
    g.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(btnFirst, g);

    JButton btnLast = new JButton("Last");
    g.gridx = 1;
    g.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(btnLast, g);

    JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
    g.gridx = 3;
    g.gridy = 2;
    panel.add(btnNext, g);

    JButton btnPrevious = new JButton("Previous");
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 3;
    panel.add(btnPrevious, g);

    JTextArea totalInventory = new JTextArea("Total Inventory\t\t\t");
    totalInventory.append(nf.format(total));
    g.gridx = 0;
    g.gridy = 6;
    panel.add(totalInventory, g);
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this will involve less guess work and produce better response

Comment: There's no guesswork here, though; MadProgrammer's answer nails the two super obvious issues here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things...

1. Call `setVisible` last, after you've constructed the primary interface
2. Add `panel` to the frame, `frame.add(panel)`

Comment: O my I can't believe that I forgot to add the panel. :(

Comment: @user13596510 Welcome to my world of "why the f**k isn't this working" :P